# I have to get the second largest count in the query's result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using a test data base Advetureworks and I want to get the second highest count in the result but I'm not getting it.

What changes do I have to make on the following query to get the desired result?

```
select pa.City,psp.Name,COUNT(he.EmployeeID) as emp_count
from HumanResources.EmployeeAddress hea
join HumanResources.Employee he on he.EmployeeID=hea.EmployeeID
join Person.Contact pc on pc.ContactID=he.ContactID
join Person.Address pa on pa.AddressID=hea.AddressID
join Person.StateProvince psp on psp.StateProvinceID=pa.StateProvinceID
where COUNT(he.EmployeeID) < (select max(count(he.employeeid)) from HumanResources.Employee)

group by pa.City,psp.Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ranking functions, try it like this:

```
;WITH a AS (
    select pa.City,psp.Name,COUNT(he.EmployeeID) as emp_count
    from HumanResources.EmployeeAddress hea
    join HumanResources.Employee he on he.EmployeeID=hea.EmployeeID
    join Person.Contact pc on pc.ContactID=he.ContactID
    join Person.Address pa on pa.AddressID=hea.AddressID
    join Person.StateProvince psp on psp.StateProvinceID=pa.StateProvinceID
    group by pa.City,psp.Name   
), b AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY emp_count DESC) num
    FROM    a
)
SELECT  *
FROM    b
WHERE   b.num = 2
```

Comment: i'm apologizing in advance because i know its a stupid question .... but i wanted to know if i can use " * " in the group by clause or not instead of writing all the column names in the group by clause /

Comment: It's not a stupid question... In the `SELECT` list of your query you can put only those columns that are in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregate columns, i.e. the ones that are generated by some aggregation function such as `COUNT(), SUM(), AVG()` etc. Otherwise you get a compilation error.

Comment: thanks for answering ...... one other thing ... how can i contact you for further queries...?

Comment: You're welcome, if there are problems with coding you can always ask on Stackoverflow, everyone will gladly help.

Answer (score 4):

I knew there was a ROW_NUMBER way of doing it as posted by Ivan G but I can never remember the syntax so here is a slightly different approach:

```
with top_cities (City, Name, emp_count) as
(
  select top 2
    pa.City,psp.Name,COUNT(he.EmployeeID) as emp_count
  from 
    HumanResources.EmployeeAddress hea
    join HumanResources.Employee he on he.EmployeeID=hea.EmployeeID
    join Person.Contact pc on pc.ContactID=he.ContactID
    join Person.Address pa on pa.AddressID=hea.AddressID
    join Person.StateProvince psp on psp.StateProvinceID=pa.StateProvinceID        
  group by 
    pa.City,psp.Name
  order by 
    emp_count desc
)
select top 1 * from top_cities order by emp_count asc
```

Comment: thanks for providing your opinion ....... i really appreciate it and it has given me a new perspective on using both "top" and "row" function

Comment: is there any other way for adding column names in the group by clause instead of naming them separately ?

Comment: No problem. But no, you've got to name the columns in the group by clause. From MSDN [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673(v=SQL.105).aspx ]: "Each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the <select> list must be included in the GROUP BY list"